# Am I understanding \$I_{DSS}\$ of this P-channel MOSFET correctly?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

I have a device that operates with a 3V lithium cell, but can optionally accept a secondary power input which disconnects the battery. This schematic shows my implementation of this function:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJf5tI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*<sub>(Circuit Lab does not appear to have a Schottky diode symbol.)</sub>*

When 3V is applied to the `DC 3V In` node, the P-channel MOSFET `Q1` ([DMG2301LK](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2301LK.pdf)) "opens" and the battery should effectively be disconnected.

The device draws approximately 10 µA in standby mode on battery. With secondary power, it is expected to draw an additional 64 µA due to the bias resistor `R_bias`. The resistor is meant to ensure that the MOSFET is in conduction when no secondary DC input is present.

Measuring current, there is ~3 µA being drawn from the cell. I was expecting < 1 µA. Reading up on the MOSFET, I am thinking this may be due to \$I_{DSS}\$ (zero gate voltage drain current). The datasheet shows that this can be -10 µA when \$V_{GS}\$ is 0V and \$V_{DS}\$ is -16V. I measured \$V_{GS}\$ to be 132 mV which coincides with the expected \$V_F\$ of the Schottky diode ([VSKY05201006](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85938/vsky05201006.pdf)) at that current.

1. Is it likely that current drawn from the cell through the MOSFET is due to \$I_{DSS}\$? *(There is a 47 µF ceramic capacitor before the transistor, not shown in the schematic, but I would not expect much leakage through it.)*
2. If so, would it be correct to assume this current is due to the slightly lower voltage (at the source) of the alternate DC input because of the voltage drop introduced by the diode?
3. Suggestions to making this more effective at disconnecting the battery when secondary DC is applied?

**Edit:**

I experimentally verified that increasing the secondary DC input voltage to 3.13V reduces current drawn from the cell to < 1 µA. So I think I've answered the question somewhat, but any additional insight regarding \$I_{DSS}\$ would still be helpful.

Comment: This could be completely mistaken, but with the orientation you have the FET in, do you end up with the body diode forward biased if the DC supply isn't a bit higher than the battery?  You see the actual drop of the Schottky because you draw real current through it, but what would be the forward voltage of the body diode at 10 uA?

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's a good point; I overlooked that. The body diode would be forward biased unless the secondary input is higher. I am unsure what its forward voltage would be at other low currents. (The chart in the datasheet shows little detail below ~500mA.)